# minceraft 1.8 to 1.11 java plugin help replace command string to int

Tags: java, replace, minecraft

i'm having trouble with the replace in one of my java files which is generating a error it says to change it to a char but i don't know if that will work.

i am new to java and really want to get this plugin working. i have fixed everything else which was outdated im just having trouble with this bit of code

```
 l.add(this.vipLayout.getColoredLine(i).replace("{ONLINE}", this.online)
```

the code is in link below
 https://github.com/joseph15562/error

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We need more information. What was the exact error? What type is `this.vipLayout.getColoredLine(i)`? The code you linked is too long, usually people post a small example that replicates the error in the question. Check out how to [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update for a better chance of someone helping

Comment: the error im getting is from the .replace 

 The method replace(char, char) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String, int)

Answer (score 1):

Your fields `online` and `max` are of the type `int`. You should use `String.valueOf(online/max)` to get a corresponding String.

Next time please google before posting a question. This is a very basic problem and can be found all over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
l.add(this.vipLayout.getColoredLine(i).replace("{ONLINE}", String.valueOf(this.online)))
```